# How I can click on img (DevExpress controll)?

Tags: ruby, eclipse, watir

How I can click on :

```
<td class="dxgvCommandColumn_Aqua dxgv" align="center">
<img title="Delete User" class="dxgvCommandColumnItem_Aqua dxgv__cci" onclick="aspxGVScheduleCommand('ctl00_ctl00_bodyPage_BodyPage_grApplicants',['CustomButton','DelAppl',0],1)" src="../images/delete.gif" alt="Delete User" style="cursor:pointer;">
</td>
```

Eclipse. Watir. Ruby.

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: What have you written?

Comment: I tried with (:src, /delete/).click but failed.
I was given advice to use xpath but I don't understand how it's aplicable in my case

Comment: browser.goto url 
browser.link(:href,"Vacancies.aspx?param=apply:2").click # This is like LOGIN button/link 
browser.text_field(:id,"ctl00_bodyPage_LoginPanel_login_I").set 'login' # Login text
browser.text_field(:id,"ctl00_bodyPage_LoginPanel_passw_I").set 'passw' # Password text
browser.div(:id,"ctl00_bodyPage_LoginPanel_btn_Login_CD").click # there is Sign In button        browser.text_field(:id,"ctl00_ctl00_bodyPage_BodyPage_grApplicants_DXFREditorcol4_I").set 'search_text' # Search line
browser...? #Line was founded and there is possibility to delete founded row.

Comment: to delete row I should click on image.
You can check code of element(this image) on which I should click to delete a row in question.

Comment: If it's help, there is picture with source and UI:
http://s020.radikal.ru/i722/1303/64/0984d1b5c659.jpg

Comment: try `browser.image(:title => "Delete User").fire_event "onclick"`

Comment: Thank you, orde. Tried, works ok )

Answer (score 0):

Per the OP, the solution was to use a `fire_event` method to trigger the `onclick` event associated with the `<img>` tag:

```
browser.image(:title => "Delete User").fire_event "onclick"
```